# Searching items in csv file python

Tags: python, csv, search

We have a csv file :

```
{a, b, c, d}
{e, a, f, b}
{w, a, k, p}
```

Also we have

```
>>x=(a,)
>>y=(b,)
>>x1=set(x)
>>y1=set(y)
>>c=x1|y1
>>print(c)

{a,b}
```

I want to count how many times {a,b} exists in csv file. In this csv file, {a,b} exists in first and second row. So count=2. How I can do this in python?

Comment: I want to find in every row , if a,b exist at the same time. Which is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: I know what you are trying to do but have you tried anything? If you haven't, you should try to do it yourself and come back when you have an actual question/problem.

Answer (score -1):

1- first use [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to convert csv to list.example would be something like this(maybe not exactly,depending on your problem):

```
import csv
with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    my_list= list(reader)
```

2- then check my_list and then count it :

```
count = 0 
for item in my_list:
    if my_list was {a,b} style:
        count+=1
```

3- since you have **n rows** and you have to check **all rows** then the best solution would be **O(n)** and the solution above is also O(n) so it's a good solution